# Data Attribute in Frame returning undefined from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The html looks like this:

```
<ul class="categoryitems">
    <li><a data-url="../po/browse_po.php" href="welcome.php" target="main">PURCHASE ORDERS</a></li>           
    <li><a data-url="../po/po_email_config.php" href="welcome.php" target="main">PO EMAILS</a></li>     
</ul>
```

Ignore the hrefs they are not relevant. I plan to prevent default on them.

What is relevent is the jquery failing:

```
$('a').click(function()
    {
        alert($(this).parent().html()); //shows the a tag with the data-url attribute
        //$(this).data('url',"..someurl.com");
        alert($(this).data('url')); //returns undefined; when the previous line is uncommented works 
        alert($(this).attr('data-url')); //this works        
    });
```

If it makes a difference the click function is wrapped in this:

```
$("#wndNavbar").ready( function() { 

});
```

Because its in a frame:

```
<frameset cols="<?=$gl_navbar_width?>,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="5" border="0">
    <frame id="wndNavbar" name="wndNavbar" src="nav_bar.php" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" noresize>
    <frame name="main" src="welcome.php" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" noresize>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/BhmcH/

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code. Especially if there is an iframe involved?  Is the `id` of your iframe actually `wndNavbar`?

Comment: thats correct i will show it in a sec

Comment: Hold on... that is NOT an `iframe` as you stated above (and below in my answer).  This is a `frame` and I believe `ready` does NOT work on a `frame`.  For that you would probably need to use `$("#wndNavbar").load();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you read the `data-url`.  this is the right way:

```
alert($(this).data('url'));
```

or

```
alert($(this).attr('data-url'));
```

Update:  Since the above doesn't seem to fix it for you, have you tried to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

or

```
$("#wndNavbar").live(function() {

});
```

instead of

```
$("#wndNavbar").ready( function() { 

});
```

UPDATE 2: You seem to be using a `frame`, NOT an `iframe`.  `ready` does not work on `frame`s, so you need to use `load`:

```
$("#wndNavbar").load( function() { 

});
```

Comment: but (as far as I know), you can't use `ready` on anything but the `document`. So try `live` instead.

Comment: Are you saying that your iframe `id` is `#wndNavbar`? Or is `#wndNavbar` inside the iframe?